# Random missile generator and air defense system

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, battle-simulation

My task in C#:

1. Random missile generator generating 2 types of missiles each second: `ThermoNuclearBomb` and `FacetBomb`

   - Missiles have properties Serial Number, Type
2. Air Defense System, that is identifying the 2 types of missiles and neutralizes each of them with a different gun (`AntiThermoGun` and `AntiFacetGun`)

   - Air Defense system has a method `AcceptMissile` that accepts a `Missile` as a parameter
   - Every `Gun` has a method `Neutralize` that accepts an appropriate `Missile` as a parameter and neutralizes only such types of missiles.
   - The Air Defense system must decide which missile will be neutralized with which gun.

I've got two interfaces:

```
public interface IMissile
    {
         int SerialNumber { get; set; }
         string Type { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public interface IGun
    {
         string Name { get; set; }
         void Neutrilize(IMissile missile);
    }
```

Of course `FacetBomb` and `ThermoNuclearBomb` class implement this interface `IMissile`:

```
public class FacetBomb : IMissile
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        private string type;
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThermoNuclearBomb:IMissile
    {
        public int SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string Type { get ; set ;  }

    }
```

Here are my two classes `AntiThermoGun` and `AntiFacetGun` that implement `IGun`:

```
public class AntiThermoGun  : IGun
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name 
        {   get {return name;}
            set { name = "AntiThermoGun"; } 
        }
        public  void Neutrilize(ThermoNuclear gun)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name + "neutrilizes" + gun.Type);

        }
    }

   public class AntiFacetGun : IGun
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = "AntiFacetGun"; }
        }
        public void Neutrilize(FacetBomb missile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.Name + "neutrilizes" + missile.Type);
        }    
    }
```

Here is my `AirDefence` class which accepts a missile and decides which missile will be neutralized with which gun:

```
public class AirDefenceSystem
    {

        public void InterceptMissile(IMissile missile)
        {
            IGun igun = null;

            switch (missile.Type)
            {
                case "ThermoNuclear":

                    igun = new AntiThermoGun();
                    break;

                case "FacetBomb":
                    igun = new AntiFacetGun();
                    break;
            }
            igun.Neutrilize(missile);
        }
    }
```

In my program.cs:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FacetBomb facetBomb = new FacetBomb { SerialNumber = 100, Type = "FacetBomb" };
            FacetBomb facetBomb2 = new FacetBomb { SerialNumber = 200, Type = "FacetBomb" };
            ThermoNuclear thermoBomb = new ThermoNuclear { SerialNumber = 500, Type = "ThermoNuclear" };

            IMissile[] objects = new IMissile[] { facetBomb, facetBomb2, thermoBomb };
            AirDefenceSystem system = new AirDefenceSystem();
            foreach (var item in objects)
            {
                system.InterceptMissile(item);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Your user profile asks for your account to be deleted. Is this still current?

Answer (score 7):

**Consider var**

Using the `var` keyword when the right-hand-side of an assignment makes the type obvious can shorten your code and make changing types much easier.

**The missile `type` is unused.**

You use `Type`, but not `type`. Remove that.

**Use constructors**

For your two missile types, the properties don't change after they've been set, so make them getter-only properties and set them in the missile constructors.

```
public interface IMissile
{
     int SerialNumber { get; }
     string Type { get; }
}

public class FacetBomb : IMissile
{
    public int SerialNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public FacetBomb(string type, int serialNumber)
    {
        Type = type;
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
    }
}
```

**Avoid using strings for type information**

This is what types are for, so remove the Type property entirely. When you need to check a type, you can use type checks.

```
public void InterceptMissile(IMissile missile)
    {
        IGun igun = null;

        if(missile is ThermoNuclearBomb)
        {
           igun = new AntiThermoGun();
        }
        else if(missile is FacetBomb)
        {
           igun = new AntiFacetGun();
        }

        igun.Neutrilize(missile);
    }
```

**It's "Neutralize" or "Neutralise"**

**Naming**

Your interface is `IMissile` but your concrete types all end in `Bomb`. You have a variable called `igun` which belies its type. If you change the type you'd then have to go around changing the name of the variable too. Consider instead a variable name that specifies its purpose, not its type.

**What is the serial number for?**

It is never used, as far as I can tell.

**Use a getter to return a specific value, not a setter**

This doesn't make much semantic sense.

```
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    {   
        get {return name;}
        set { name = "AntiThermoGun"; } 
    }
```

If I call `.Name = "foo"` `.Name` will next return "AntiThermoGun". Instead, stop me from setting `.Name` at all:

```
    public string Name 
    {   
        get {return "AntiThermoGun";}
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

When I first looked at your code I thought it wasn't a bad start for a beginner.
But after carefully looking at it there are so many mistakes here and there that I can no longer say so, so excuse me for my ruthlessness.

Most of this mistakes happen with your properties, let's look at an example:

> ```
> public class AntiFacetGun : IGun
> {
>     private string name;
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get { return name; }
>         set { name = "AntiFacetGun"; }
>     }
> }
> ```

The only reason I can think of you wrote that it's because you don't fully know how properties work.
When you create your `AntiFacetGun` with `var gun = new AntiFacetGun()`, the gun name would be null.
When you finally set the the gun name with `gun.Name = "thisName"` the name will be `AntiFacetGun`.
The final result will be a sad programmer thinking of why `gun.Name` is not "thisName".

A better approach would be to have all your properties read-only.

```
public class AntiFacetGun : IGun
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "AntiFacetGun"; }
    }
}
```

This not only solves the problem described before but also doesn't let the properties of your guns to be changed.
This is special relevant for your `AirDefenceSystem`. 
If I create a `FacetBomb` with `Type` different from `FacetBomb` your 
`InterceptMissile` will throw a `NullReferenceException` putting the lives of millions at risk.

In your `FacetBomb` class you also left over the field `type` there that is not being used anywhere.

Last but not least you don't have way to know if you successfully Intercepted a missile or not. 
If a new type of Missile appears the `NullReferenceException` will be thrown as described before.
This is because your `switch` statement doesn't have a `default` case ignoring all other possible guns.

It would be nice to extract the Gun creation logic into a separate method due to single responsibility pattern.

This would be the resulting code if you would have applied everything I said.

```
public interface IMissile
{
     int SerialNumber { get; }
     string Type { get; }
}

public interface IGun
{
     string Name { get; }
     void Neutrilize(IMissile missile);
}

public class FacetBomb : IMissile
{
    public FacetBomb(string serialNumber){
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public int SerialNumber { get; private set; }
    public string Type { get { return "FacetBomb"; } }
}

public class ThermoNuclearBomb : IMissile
{
    public FacetBomb(string serialNumber){
        SerialNumber = serialNumber;
    }

    public string Type { get { return "ThermoNuclearBomb"; } }
}

public class AntiThermoGun  : IGun
{
    public string Name { get { return "AntiThermoGun"; } }

    public void Neutrilize(ThermoNuclear gun)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name + "neutrilizes" + gun.Type);
    }
}

public class AntiFacetGun : IGun
{
    public string Name { get { return "AntiFacetGun"; } }

    public void Neutrilize(FacetBomb missile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name + "neutrilizes" + missile.Type);
    }    
}

public class AirDefenceSystem
{
    private IGun GetGun(IMissile missile)
    {
        switch (missile.Type)
        {
            case "ThermoNuclear":
                return new AntiThermoGun();
            case "FacetBomb":
                return new AntiFacetGun();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public bool InterceptMissile(IMissile missile)
    {
        var gun = GetGun(missile);
        if(gun == null){
            return false;
        }
        igun.Neutrilize(missile);
        return true;
    }
}
```